# Videogularjs AutoPlay not working

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I have a site where I can show two videos at the same time.
There is a main video, and the seconday that is an adv video that needs to be shown at some specific moment and then dissapears.

But there is an issue because the AutoPlay function is not working. it seem as if it were in play mode (because I cannot see the play button but I can see the pause one), but the image is freeze.

The URL is: https://www.granojo.com/video/10380 play the first video and wait 5 seconds and the second video will appears on the right.

I set the property vg-auto-play in true, but when the video is loaded, it's not working. If I set it to false, and then manually put play the video can be reproduceable.

I also tried with:

```
vg-player-ready="onAdvReady($API)"
```

And then:

```
$scope.onAdvReady = function(API) {
          this.advApi = API;
          this.advApi.play();
          this.advApi.setVolume(0);
        };
```

But I get the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I make it works by changing the second video to a pure HTML5 video player... I know it wasn't the right solution, but I don;t have any requirements to put there another videogular payer..